# When and why should i trigger pg_stat_reset()?

Tags: postgresql, performance, vacuum

I am trying to understand how to monitor and tune postgresql performance. I started with exploring tables `pg_stat_all_tables`, `pg_stat_statements` in order to gather information about live tuples, dead tuples, last autovacuum time etc. There were some usefull information about `n_live_tuples` (near to real rows count in table) and `n_dead_tup` util i run `pg_stat_reset` query. After that i have some strange results - there are less `n_live_tup` than `n_dead_tup`. I can't find any articles/docs about why and when (some use cases) should i run `pg_stat_reset` query. Can somebody explain me that or provide some useful resources?

Comment: `n_live_tup` wasn't correctly calculated until first vacuum/autovacuum occurred. After that statistics looks as i expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is ok to run `pg_stat_reset()` occasionally, like once per month, to get a fairly up-to-date view on what is going on in your database.

But don't do that too often, as there is a down side to it: the system relevant autovacuum process relies on these statistics, so you will miss a couple of autovacuum (and autoanalyze) runs if you do that. That may or may not be a problem in your database, but at any rate I wouldn't do it too often. If you can, manually `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE` the database after calling `pg_stat_reset()`.

There is no such problem with `pg_stat_statements_reset()`, so run that as often as you please.

The best thing for you would be to have a monitoring software that checks the values of the statistics regularly and provides you with a the development (differences to the previous run). Then you never have to reset the statistics and still have a good overview over what is going on.